# laravel Method Illuminate\\Validation\\Validator::false does not exist

Tags: laravel

(im new with laravel)
postman api test error like this all the time

```
"status": false,
"message": "Method Illuminate\\Validation\\Validator::false does not exist."
```

the function for register a new user for test

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\ِAuth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;


class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create User
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */

    public function createUser(Request $request)
    {
        try {

             $validateUser = Validator::make($request->all(),
            [      
                'name'=> 'required',
                'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
                'password' => 'required'
            ]);

            if($validateUser->false()){
                return response()->json([
                    'status' => false,
                    'message' => 'validation error',
                    'errors' => $validateUser->errors()
                ], 401);
            }

          $user = User::ceate([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'message' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password
          ]);
           
            return response()->json([
                'status' => true,
                'message' => 'User Created Succssfully',
                'token' => $userInfo
            ], 200);

        } catch(\Throwable $th){
            return response()->json([
                'status' => false,
                'message' => $th->getMessage()
            ], 401);
        }
    }

}
```

can any one help me i use (use Validator;) and still get same error !!

Comment: its should be  $validateUser->fails() instead of  $validateUser->false()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$validateUser->fails()` instead of `$validateUser->false()`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for fails, not false, from the Laravel documentation:

```php
<?php
 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
 
class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Store a new blog post.
     */
    public function store(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
            'body' => 'required',
        ]);
 
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('post/create')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }
```

so your code is going to be:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\ِAuth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;


class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create User
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */

    public function createUser(Request $request)
    {
        try {

             $validateUser = Validator::make($request->all(),
            [      
                'name'=> 'required',
                'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
                'password' => 'required'
            ]);

            if($validateUser->fails()){
                return response()->json([
                    'status' => false,
                    'message' => 'validation error',
                    'errors' => $validateUser->errors()
                ], 401);
            }

          $user = User::ceate([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'message' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password
          ]);
           
            return response()->json([
                'status' => true,
                'message' => 'User Created Succssfully',
                'token' => $userInfo
            ], 200);

        } catch(\Throwable $th){
            return response()->json([
                'status' => false,
                'message' => $th->getMessage()
            ], 401);
        }
    }

}
```

See [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#manually-creating-validators) for more information.